# I'm trying to perform a Chi Square Test on R but not getting a correct rejection rate?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

```
ChiTest = function(bin,sample) {
  observed <- hist(sample,breaks=seq(0,4,by=1/bin),plot=FALSE) ;
  return((bin/length(sample))*sum((observed$counts-length(sample)/bin)^2))
}



sample = one_side_normal(500) ;bin=10 ; alpha = 0.95 ; M = 1000 ; test_rejected = 0 

for(i in 1:M) {
  sample = one_side_normal(500) ;
  test_rejected = test_rejected+(ChiTest(bin,sample) > qchisq(alpha,bin-1));
}
print(paste(c("Our One Sided Normal Sample has a rejection rate of", test_rejected*100/M, "%"),collapse = ""))
```

In the above code I'm trying to run a Chi Square Test to find out the rejection rate of my one sided normal sample. I haven't included the code to define `one_side_normal()` as I don't believe it's necessary but it's producing a random sample from the positive normal distribution. No matter what value I put in for `bin` I'm getting a rejection rate of 100%. Why is this the case?

```
`bin` = number of partitions ,
alpha = confidence level ,
M = times running test
```

Comment: hi how is the code above supposed to work? What is your actual question? Can you provide some sample data and how it runs

Answer (score 2):

In situations where providing code is helpful, it is almost always better for it to be code that actually runs. It's not just a matter of `one_side_normal` not being defined, you also don't say how you handle values over 4, which will give an error in `hist`

However, in this case the answers are simple enough.

Firstly: Your code rejects the null hypothesis because the null hypothesis is not true. Your code divides the range of the random variable up into bins of equal width, and compares the observed count to the count that would be expected if the bins had equal probability. That is, you are doing a goodness of fit test to a uniform distribution.  Since you are simulating from a half-normal distribution, it's not surprising you reject the hypothesis that it's uniform.

Secondly: Your code divides the data into `4*bin` bins (a range of 0 to 4, with width `1/bin`), but you use `bin-1` degrees of freedom for the test and use `bin/length(sample)` as a proportion.

If you define `ChiTest` as

```
ChiTest = function(bin,sample) {
  observed <- hist(sample,breaks=seq(0,4,by=1/bin),plot=FALSE) ;
  return((4*bin/length(sample))*sum((observed$counts-length(sample)/4/bin)^2))
}
```

and you simulate from your null hypothesis of a uniform distribution, you will get a rejection rate around 5%.